# CUDA 8.0 installation fails because of Visual Studio

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I have NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M. So it's respective CUDA distribution is 8.0. So I ve been trying to install CUDA 8.0 GPU Computing toolkit, the status going unknown and the installer couldn't find the respective VS for CUDA 8.0.

[image]

After closing the installation window shown above, the CUDA 8.0 files installed vanished. 
I tried manually to find the Visual Studio 2015, I couldn't find either.

Any help on installation is appreciable.

Comment: There is no error message in your image.

Comment: No error. but VS is not installed. I need it to run CUDA 8.0

Comment: Did you bother to read the installation instructions? Download and install a supported VS verison *first*, then install the CUDA toolkit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio is a programming IDE. CUDA comes with some built in add-ons for VS that only install if you already have VS installed. As noted in the message "The following information [...] does not describe CUDA toolkit install status."

Unless you have VS and are trying to install the add-ons, your install was successful and you should mark this resolved.

Comment: After closing the installation window, I couldn't find the installation files for CUDA 8.0 too. And there's no existing VS available in my computer.

Comment: by default the cuda toolkit 8.0 is installed to 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0 on windows and the code samples to C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v8.0

Comment: that disappears after closing this installation window.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but check the default install locations. If the files aren't there, install again and note the locations

Comment: Until closing the installation window, those files are there in the default location I provided. After closing it, v8.0 disappears. Do you understand now what I am saying ?

Comment: Did you cancel the installation instead of proceeding to the end?

Comment: I did not cancel it. I proceeded to next as shown in the above image

Comment: For typical usage of CUDA, it's normally expected that you install a supported VS version first.  Read the CUDA windows install guide for CUDA 8.0.  The CUDA installer does not install VS for you.  You have to do this yourself, separately, first.

Comment: I installed VS 2015 which is the supported version for CUDA 8.0 and then tried installing CUDA, Yet installation fails

Comment: Your installer picture shows that VS2015 was not found.  So there is something wrong with your VS2015 install. For instance, you may not have installed VC++